# Using AND in Update clause - Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database

My Code

```
$names = $_GET['name'];
    $s = "update users set filelocation='$newname' where sessionusername = '$u' AND name = '$names'";
```

the above does not work, while the below works.

```
$s = "update users set filelocation='$newname' where sessionusername = '$u'";
```

How do i get it to work? every variable has a value that matches the database.

Thanks.

This is where I declare $names -

```
$names = mysqli_real_escape_string($connect, trim($_GET['name']));
echo $names;
ini_set('display_errors','On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
if(isset($_POST['submitted'])){
```

Comment: the row does not get updated, if i use the first method.

Comment: There's nothing about AND that shouldn't work in an update. I find the variable name `$names` ominous though - are you sure it's a string and not an array or something similar?

Comment: looks like an issue with $names...can u help?

Answer (score 1):

Try to echo $s. This will output the query with the variabele values so you can check if there are any errors with these.

Comment: this is what I am using to get names -- header("location:upload_file.php?name=$name");  in the header i see the name perfectly..y not working then?

Comment: It could be that you need to escape some quotes in $names using mysql_real_escape_string()

Comment: @sampleJACk i escaped $names.this is what i get --update users set filelocation='67EEC.zip' where sessionusername = 'developer@developer.com' AND name = ''

Comment: You said echo'ing $names works. What is the output when you try this?

Comment: Could it be that where you're declaring $s, $names is out of scope?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see any mistakes here. Do you get any error messages? Can you post all relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Plus use this this functions
[mysql_real_escape_string](http://ru.php.net/mysql_real_escape_string)
[mysqli::real_escape_string](http://ru.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)